# ListView does not show data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from firebase to show in a ListView but when i run the app, the ListView does not show any data. I see the ListView but there is no data. Can you tell me why and what can i do? I had the same problem when i tried with spinner.

```
public class CitiesList extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference databasePaths;
private ListView ListViewCities;
private ArrayList<String> ArrayListCities;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCities;
Paths info;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cities_list);

    ListViewCities = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCities);
    ArrayListCities = new ArrayList<>();

    databasePaths = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Paths");

    databasePaths.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot items: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                info = items.getValue(Paths.class);
                ArrayListCities.add(info.city);

            }

            adapterCities = new ArrayAdapter<>(CitiesList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            ListViewCities.setAdapter(adapterCities);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });




}}
```

Comment: How are u sending the  ArrayListCities to the list view?

Comment: That was my mistake, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set new list to adapter, which you are not doing into your current code. Modify below line

```
adapterCities = new ArrayAdapter<>(CitiesList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
ListViewCities.setAdapter(adapterCities);
```

as

```
adapterCities = new ArrayAdapter<>(CitiesList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayListCities);
ListViewCities.setAdapter(adapterCities);
```

---

As a side note, try to follow coding style guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in Adapter the TextView from where the adapter will set the data.

So after R.layout.XXXX, you need to pass:
**android.R.id.text1**